# Why is QWidget being destroyed? (PyQt)

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread, qwidget, qtimer

So I have the main window. When I click a button in the main window, a new widget is created (in a new window):

```
    self.doorButton.clicked.connect(self.open_door)
    def open_door(self):
        self.doorwin = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.doorui = doorwinActions(self.doors)
        self.doorui.setupUi(self.doorwin)
        self.doorwin.show()
```

The new QWidget or *doorwin* has only one widget - tableWidget

I use the object *self.doors* to populate the table. Now since I have a worker thread (QThread) updating the said object  (*self.doors*), I use QTimer to repopulate the table every 1 second.

```
class doorwinActions(Ui_doorWin):
    def __init__(self,doors):
        self.doors = doors

    # update setupUi
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        super().setupUi(Widget)
        Widget.move(self.left, self.top)  # set location for window
        Widget.setWindowTitle(self.title) # change title
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda:self.popTable())
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def popTable(self):
        mutex.lock()
        entries = len(self.doors)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(entries)
        for i in range(entries):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.doors[i][0])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.doors[i][1].get_id()))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,2,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.doors[i][1].get_name()))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,3,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.doors[i][2])))
        mutex.unlock()
```

When I run the program, it runs smoothly. It opens a new window. If the *self.doors* object is updated while the window is open, the GUI reflects the change.
BUT, the problem occurs if I reopen the window. If I close the window and then click on the button again, the program crashes with the error:

**RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QTableWidget has been deleted**

From what I understand about my code, when I close the window, the whole widget window (and the table) is deleted. And when I click on the doorButton, new Qwidget/table are created. So, the question is, why would it delete something it just created?

**What (sort of) works?** - If I move the setup of the door window to the main window's setup, it works. So the open_door function would just be:

```
    def open_door(self):
        self.doorwin.show()
```

The rest would be in the main window setup. But the problem is, then even when I close the window,  the QTimer is still going in the background, just eating up processing power.

So, either,

1. How do I stop the event when the window is closed OR
2. How do I stop the tableWidget from being deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is garbage collection.

When you do this:

```
    def open_door(self):
        self.doorwin = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.doorui = doorwinActions(self.doors)
        self.doorui.setupUi(self.doorwin)
        self.doorwin.show()
```

You are creating a *new* QWidget. It has absolutely *no* other reference but `self.doorwin`. This means that if you call `open_door` again, you will be *overwriting* `self.doorwin`, and since the previous widget was not referenced anywhere else, it will get deleted *along with all its contents*.

Now, QTimers are tricky. You created a QTimer in `doorwinActions` and QTimers can be persistent even if they have no parent: they keep going on until they're stopped or deleted, and they can only be deleted explicitly or when their *parent* is deleted (with the exception of timers created with the static `QTimer.singleShot()` function).

Finally, you must remember that PyQt (like PySide) is a *binding*. It creates "connections" with the objects created in Qt (let's call them "C++ objects"), and through those bindings we can access those objects, their functions and so on, through python *references*.
But, and this is of foremost importance, both objects can have a different lifespan:

- the python reference can be deleted, and the Qt object can still exist;
- the Qt object can be destroyed, yet we still have the python object that *referenc****ed*** (past tense) it;

This is exactly what happens in your case: the `self.doorui` object is overwritten, but it has an object (the QTimer, `self.timer`) that is still alive, so the Python garbage collector will *not* delete it, and the timer is still able to call `popTable`. But, at that point, the widget (`self.doorwin`) and its contents have been destroyed on the "C++ side", which causes your crash: while `self.tableWidget` still exists as a *python reference*, the actual widget has been destroyed along with its parent widget, and calling its functions causes a fatal error as the binding cannot find the actual object.

---

Now, how to solve that?

There are various options, and it depends on what you need to do with that window. But, before that, there is something much more important.

You have been manually editing a file generated by `pyuic`, but those files are not intended for that. They are to be considered like "resource" files, used only for their purpose (the `setupUi` method), and *never*, ***EVER*** be manually edited. Doing that is considered bad practice and is conceptually wrong for many reasons - and their header clearly warns about that. To read more about the commonly accepted approaches for those files, read the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

One of those reasons is exactly related to the garbage collection issue explained above.

Note that subclassing the pyuic form class alone is also discouraged (and pointless if you want to extend the *widget* behavior); the most common, accepted and suggested practice is to create a class that inherits both from the Qt widget class *and* the UI class. The following code assumes that you have *recreated* the file with `pyuic` and named `ui_doorwin.py`:

```
# ...

from ui_doorwin import Ui_DoorWin

# ...

class DoorWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_DoorWin):
    def __init__(self, doors):
        super().__init__()
        self.doors = doors
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QTimer(self) # <-- IMPORTANT! Note the "self" argument
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.popTable)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def popTable(self):
        # ...
```

With the above code you can be sure that whenever the widget gets deleted for any reason, the timer will be destroyed along with it, so the function will not be called trying to access objects that don't exist anymore.

If you need to keep using an existing instance of the window, the solution is pretty simple: create a `None` instance (or class) attribute and check if it already exists before creating a new one:

```
class SomeParent(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    doorwin = None

    # ...

    def open_door(self):
        if not self.doorwin:
            self.doorwin = DoorWin()
        self.doorwin.show()
```

The above code will not stop the table from updating, which is something you might not want, so you might choose to start and stop the timer depending on when the window is actually shown:

```
class DoorWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_DoorWin):
    def __init__(self, doors):
        super().__init__()
        self.doors = doors
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.popTable)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not event.spontaneous():
            self.timer.start()

    def hideEvent(self, event):
        if not event.spontaneous():
            self.timer.stop()
```

<sup>The `event.spontaneous()` check above is to prevent stopping the timer if the show/hide event is caused by system calls, like minimizing the window or changing desktop. It's up to you to decide if you want to keep the timer going on and process all data, even if the window is not shown.</sup>

Then, if you want to completely destroy the window when it's closed *and* when a new one is opened, do the following:

```
class DoorWin(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_DoorWin):
    def __init__(self, doors):
        # ... (as above)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
```

and then ensure that the widget exists (note that if it's closed by the user the reference still exists):

```
class SomeParent(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    doorwin = None

    # ...

    def open_door(self):
        if self.doorwin:
            try:
                self.doorwin.close()
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
        self.doorwin = DoorWin()
        self.doorwin.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is really helpful.
1. I am not using the file generated by the _pyuic_. I have a separate file for the code I write.
2. I am getting ** type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'WA_DeleteOnClose'**. I am using PyQt6, I am unsure why I am getting this error if I am being honest.
3. If I use the `self.`, the widget isn't deleted (but the QTimer still goes on).
4. I found an extremely [hacky solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70980356/10192648), but I would prefer if WA_DeleteOnClose works

Comment: Found the WA_DeleteOnClose attribute, but on closing, it doesn't stop the QTimer

Comment: My apologies for the comment spam. QTimer stops if I pass self with it `timer = QTimer(self)`. But now the `if not self.doorwin:` part doesn't work, because python still has the pointer even though the widget has been deleted. But it is a nice-to-have for my project, so I live with it.

Comment: 1. subclassing the UI class only is discouraged as well as editing it (the result is almost the same, that class is a python object, not a QWidget), the only proper way to use subclassing with those objects is with multiple inheritance of *both* the Qt widget *and* the pyuic classess; 2. since Qt6 all flags/enums can only be accessed through their namespace (the flag or enum class name); 3. the `self` argument is mandatory if you want it to be stopped along with the deletion of the parent (I specifically wrote that it was important!); see the update for the reference issue on deletion.

Comment: 1. Yes, that is how I’m doing it. I’m actually taking a QWidget as an argument when creating the object and then inheriting and running the setupUI
2. Okay, thank you. Will keep that in mind
3. Don’t know how I missed that, my bad
4. I’m not sure what you mean by “see the update for the reference issue on deletion”

Comment: 4 (contd). If you’re referring to ‘doorwin =None’, then on closing the window, doorwin doesn’t switch back to None, the object is still referenced even if it’s destroyed

Comment: 1. I've seen that, and I still suggest you to avoid that: subclassing the pyuic form class to add functionalities is pointless, add those to a subclass that actually inherits from the widget *and* the form class (as done above), so that the object remains consistent to its members (and you also get a simpler code that is also more clear to read and debug): if you need to override the Qt widget functions, you would need to subclass it anyway; 4. I've updated the post (see the edit history to see the changes): now it properly closes the current widget reference *if* the widget actually exists.

Comment: Note that closing the window does not (nor can) immediately delete the python object reference: while you could connect the `destroyed` signal to a function that resets the reference to `None` you cannot be sure that it will be called immediately: deletion is an event that is queued in the event queue and can only be processed when control returns back to event loop and after processing previously queued events. The `WA_DeleteOnClose` is only to ensure that the widget gets deleted when closed, not to immediately clear its references.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been extremely helpful. I have now subclassed it as you said. And the code is cleaner. I saw my method in a YT video and blindly followed it. I have added the try/except part too. Makes my code much better

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My two proposed solutions are the same. If I stop the QTimer on window closing, it no longer gives me the error.

```
self.exitButton.clicked.connect(self.close_win)
def close_win(self):
    self.timer.stop()
    self.Widget.close()
```

Comment: No. Sorry, but that is not a good solution. Try to close the window with the close button and you'll see.

Comment: @musicamante Actually I was using `self.Widget.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowCloseButtonHint, False)` too, but I can see why this isn't the best solution